# Open ports for Apache Tomcat-7.0.32 on Linux Mandriva

Tags: java, linux, networking

I installed **Apache Tomcat-7.0.32** on **Linux Mandriva** and I want to make it accessible. for this I need to open ports in **iptables**.

I added the following rules-

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8081 --syn -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8010 --syn -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8444 --syn -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8006 --syn -j ACCEPT
```

then save and restart iptables -

```
/etc/init.d/iptables save
/etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

verify, that ports is open -

```
netstat -tulpn | less
```

I am running command -

```
netstat-ntpl | grep java
```

and see -

[image]

When I disable the firewall, I see the start page of the server on request -

```
http://server_ip:8081/
```

When enable - server not accessible from outside.

In what may be the cause?
I would be most grateful for the information!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is not related to Tomcat configuration. Make sure that you add accept iptables rules before reject rules

Comment: Whew! I added, as you said, and it worked! Thank you again! `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8081 --syn -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8010 --syn -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8444 --syn -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8006 --syn -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 1):

Ports used by tomcat should be in tomcat configuration.
However, in case of doubts, you may want to use lsof utility to find out details about what programs use what TCP or UDP ports, and local sockets.

```
lsof -Pni
lsof -Uni
```

To find out what exactly happens, and what programs are trying to access what ports, and/or are blocked by the firewall, you could also use tcpdump utility.

```
tcpdump -i eth0
```

You can grep outputs of these programs or use switches to filter what kind of  information is to be displayed. What you do wrong may be, that you add your firewall rules at the end of configuration, while iptables configuration ( firewall packets processing ) comes from the top/beginning - so when you add ACCEPTs it probably makes sense to add it at the beginning of iptables configuration file rather than at the end.

This question probably should be moved to superuser.com